# UIAlertView when using certain characters in textfield

Tags: ios, ipad

I implemented the following code in a different app, but for some reason it is not working in my current app. The UIAlertView does not show, even if the "forbidden" characters are entered in the textfield. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSCharacterSet * set1 = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];

    if ([textField1.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set1].location != NSNotFound) {


        UIAlertView *errorAlert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Only numbers are allowed in this field."delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK."otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlert1 show];

        textField1.text=@"";
    }

}
```

Comment: mark breakpoint in this method and check if this is getting called or not

Comment: I did as you suggested. The method is not getting called... what now?

Comment: what about "reaching inside if" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your object delegate to the textfield. Check if your method is used when the user ends editing.

Comment: The method is not being used at all... I don't know what I am doing wrong. It works just fine in my other app.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that was it. I needed to add "textField1.delegate = self;"

Comment: @GeorgeFriday: it delegate wasn't set how your delegate method was getting called?

Comment: I am kind of new to this, so I forgot to set the delegate in my current app. I looked at the code of my working app and Per Arve's response, and it started to make sense. Thanks all for responding.